# Symlinked Dockerfile with Git submodule does not work

Tags: git, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a project which has:

- Git submodule with boilerplate code, including Dockerfile
- Docker Compose specific to the project

I get an error when trying to build Docker image, which is probably related to the symlinks. I symlink the Dockerfile from Git submodule as follows.

I want to keep everything Docker-related in `docker` directory in repo. My structure is:

```
- boilerplate (Git submodule):
  - python:
    - Dockerfile (linked)
    - .dockerignore (linked)
  - ...
- docker:
  - Dockerfile (symlink)
  - docker-compose.yml
  - .env
- .dockerignore (symlink)
- Makefile
- ...
```

My Makefile creates those symlinks:

```
init:
    -git clone --recurse-submodule git@github.com:org/boilerplate
    ln --force -s ../boilerplate/python/.dockerignore .dockerignore
    ln --force -s ../boilerplate/python/Dockerfile docker/Dockerfile
```

My Docker Compose uses the Dockerfile to run services:

```
services:
   api:
     image: api
     build:
       # move to the project root
       context: ..
       dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile
     env_file: .env
     ports:
       - "5000:5000"
     volumes:
       - .:/app
```

I try to build and run Docker Compose with:

```
COMPOSE_DOCKER_CLI_BUILD=1  DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 \
docker compose --file docker/docker-compose.yml up --build --detach
```

I get an error:

```
failed to solve: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount2107585599/boilerplate/python/Dockerfile.poetry: no such file or directory
```

**Question:** why is this happening? With context `..`, the build is done in the project root, and symlinks (even being relative) should work. I also tried hard links, but it doesn't change anything. I do not want to copy files, since updating Git submodule would then not update the copies.